# Adding <link rel=preload> to fontawesome-webfont.woff2 to boost website speed

Tags: functions, google

Since the google speed insights report suggests adding a

to speed up the loading of the following resources

https://www.beautyandhealthspace.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/bower/font-awesome/fonts/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0

I am wondering how could I possibly achieve that!

More concretely, I've thrown a glance to the header.php file of both the main and the child theme, but since they are coded in PHP I can't really figure out on my own how to add any HTML to it.

There should be for sure a way to inject HTML into the webpage by means of recurring to some php-function in the header.php file. I'm very far from being a developer.

Comment: You can add HTML to your header.php - it's not easy to offer more advice than that considering you haven't provided any of the code or explained what HTML you would like added.  I'm also struggling to understand what adding HTML to your header.php and the first part of your question have in common?  Are you looking to manually add the rel="preload" to that font?

Answer (score 1):

If your theme is any good it will use [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) to include fonts in the head of your site. This gives you access to the [`style_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_tag/) filter, which you can use to modify the html of the font link. Like this:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag','wpse366869_preload_styles', 10, 4 );
function wpse366869_preload_styles( $html, $handle, $href, $media ) {

    // do this only when 'fontawesome-webfont' is mentioned in the html
    if( 0 != strpos( $html, 'fontawesome-webfont' ) ) {
        $html = str_replace( '<', '<rel="preload "', $html );
    }
    
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: In row 4, there is a missing closing bracket.

Comment: thanks, fixed it